# android - How to handle the exception when the image is loading from web

Tags: android

In my application i am adding the views dynamically to the linear layout. Each view contains the image. The entire linear layout in the scroll view. Initially images are loading correctly. Suppose i am scrolling the screen up/down then i am getting the out of memory exception. please can any body help me.

Following is my code please refer that.

```
Code
```

**This is in activity**

//Itemurl is a string

//holder is Viewholder instance

DownLoadImageInAThreadHandler_tracked(ImageUrl,holder);

```
Method
```

private void DownLoadImageInAThreadHandler_tracked(final String imgurl,final ViewHolder holder) 
        {

```
        //Thread for getting the attributes values
         Thread t = new Thread() 
         {
             public void run()
             {                      
                 try
                 {

                     Drawable drawable = getDrawableFromUrl_tracked(imgurl);                        
                     System.out.println("Drawable(after downloading):"+drawable);                        
                     if(drawable != null)
                     {                                              
                        holder.trackedimgURL.setImageDrawable(drawable);
                        holder.trackedimgURL.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.trackedprogress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);   
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         System.out.println("Set the default image(drawable is null)");
                         holder.trackedimgURL.setImageResource(R.drawable.giftsuggestionsnoimage);                           
                     }                                               
                 }
                 catch(Exception exp)
                 {
                     System.out.println("Exception in DownLoadImageInAThread : " + exp.getMessage());
                 }
             }                                                  
         };
         t.start();             
    }

    public Drawable getDrawableFromUrl_tracked(String url) 
    {

        Drawable image = null;

        try {
            InputStream in = (java.io.InputStream) new java.net.URL(url).getContent();
            if (in != null) {
                image = Drawable.createFromStream(in, "image");
                in.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
             ex.printStackTrace();

        }
        return image;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are creating a lot of Bitmap objects in memory.

Did you consider using the ListView-Adapter pattern?

Comment: I am not using a list activity in this. I am creating two custom adapters extend and adding the views dynamically to them.

Comment: how can i solve this issue?Is there any code which helps this?

Comment: Use a ListView! Unless you have a use case where you cannot.